# RabbitMQ CreateConnection issues - works in one app but not in another

Tags: c#, wpf, rabbitmq

So here is the connection code.

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
{
    HostName = "myserver",
    UserName = "testuser",
    Password = "testuserpassword"
};

using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
 using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "LOG",
                                 durable: false,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: null);

            string message = "Hello World!";
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                                 routingKey: "LOG",
                                 basicProperties: null,
                                 body: body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
        }
```

I test this in a console app and everything works fine and I could send and receive messages.

If i then copy and paste the same code from above into my WPF app, I get an exception here

```
connection = factory.CreateConnection()
```

Exception

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in RabbitMQ.Client.dll
>
> Additional information: No ip address could be resolved for myserver

If I change "myserver" to the server ip I get the same error.
Don't understand why the code works in one app and not the other.

Comment: What is the API URL you are trying to access? Also show the code inside CreateConnection() function.

Comment: I haven't shown the code because I didn't think it was relevant, the code does not get that far. API url? I haven't a clue. I am using a tutorial like this and it doesn't mention API url. https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-dotnet.html

Comment: API URL is where we post messages to the MQ. I can show you a sample code to make a connection and POST a message, but not sure if that will be helpful. So I wanted to see how exactly how you are creating the connection.

Comment: oh right, I don't know the URL. I imagine the RabbitMQ .net client creates. As you can see from my code, I don't enter a url anywhere and it works fine in the console app.

Comment: Is your MQ running on a different machine? If yes, check if you are able to ping that machine using it's IP. And the URL is something like this- http://<IP or machine name>:<port number>/rpa/api/message

Comment: Yes it is running fine. I think you are missing the point that this code works in my console application so pinging is irrelevant. I believe it is related to the WPF application.

Comment: I see. Seems like some configuration is missed. Check the ConnectionFactory details and compare it with the one in your Console app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Problem solved. It looks like it was something as simple as the Exception settings. For some reason the console app was set to not break on the connection exceptions and the WPF app was set to break. Everything now works.

Strange that the exceptions are being generated, especially about not resolving the server name or IP address but yet it still works.

Comment: Glad you found it.

Comment: What was the exception setting that you changed? I've run into the same issue

Comment: @Gaz83 what changes did you make to fix this? I'm facing a similar trouble but for the console app instead.

Comment: @ValerianPereira Sorry this was a long time ago. The only advice I can give, based on my answer, is to run the console app and watch the output window in visual studio. The exceptions will show there. Then change the settings to break on that type.

Answer (score 9):

It did because the exception setting, if you look into the RMQ .net client source code, at the beginning it will try to connect your ip address with IPv6 Protocol, if your are connecting an IPv4 address this step will fail and throw System.ArgumentException: No ip address could be resolved for 'your ip address', but the RMQ .net client will catch this exception and move forward to try connect your ip address with IPv4 Protocol.

```
 if (ShouldTryIPv6(endpoint))
        {
            try {
                m_socket = ConnectUsingIPv6(endpoint, socketFactory, connectionTimeout);
            } catch (ConnectFailureException)
            {
                m_socket = null;
            }
        }

        if (m_socket == null && endpoint.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
        {
            m_socket = ConnectUsingIPv4(endpoint, socketFactory, connectionTimeout);
        }
```

if yous set to break on the connection exceptions, your force the ArgumentException to throw.

```
  public virtual async Task ConnectAsync(string host, int port)
    {
        AssertSocket();
        var adds = await Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync(host).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var ep = TcpClientAdapterHelper.GetMatchingHost(adds, sock.AddressFamily);
        if (ep == default(IPAddress))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No ip address could be resolved for " + host);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the offending code and for a clear explanation. Your answer is the only place online that I have found that actually explains this.

Comment: Using exceptions as normal control flow is just annoying.. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the *CreateConnection* issues by disabling *Just My Code* in Visual Studio and running the app. I was first pointed in the wrong direction because Masstransit uses throws, in the networking libraries, functionally. That gave me the feeling that my config settings were wrong or my services not running, thus not reachable.

After a stubborn extra F5 I got an error that the assembly *System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions* couldn't be loaded. I added a binding redirect for it and everything worked like it should:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```